# What should I call a switch statement in an UI where users won't know what a switch statement is?

Tags: terminology, toggle

I'm designing a product where a user can build a decision tree. There are different kinds of decision nodes they can add: true/false rules, exclusion rules, and switch statements.

I'm afraid of calling these nodes "Switch Statements" because the vast majority of our users will not be programmatically-inclined.

In one to two words, how would you describe a switch statement so that it's clear to users that they'll be defining an attribute, then creating cases for different values?

**Ideas so far:**

- Attribute Switch
- Value Switch
- Value Rule

Comment: multiple-choice rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the important thing to communicate here is that there are *multiple* branches (unlike most other rules that are yes/no true/false).

I would call it something like **multi-value switch** or **multi-value branch**.

I don't know what your exact use case is, but the system you describe sounds pretty complicated, requiring some learning on the users's part.  So, I wouldn't worry a huge amount about making everything instantly recognizable.  That may not be possible.  Just make sure there is a good way to get help.

Comment: Yeah, it's quite complicated. I guess I'm just going for a balance between learnability and recall. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 4):

Choice/Choose. (Which is in fact the keyword some languages have used for this operation.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd just call them **decision-junctions**, that metaphor should convey the meaning to non-programmers. Also consider,: Junctions, road forks, choice forks, forks, etc.

[image: Image of a signpost showing different directions]

[image: Photo of a road fork]